# Why isn't $\mathbb Z_9 \cong \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$ by the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I was reading the answer to this question: [Explicit descriptions of groups of order 45](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108405/explicit-descriptions-of-groups-of-order-45) and the accepted answer says the Sylow $3$-subgroup is either isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_9$ or $\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$. But now my question is: **Why isn't $\mathbb Z_9 \cong \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$ by the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups?**

The fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups says: *Every finite abelian group is the direct product of cyclic groups*. (Herstein)

So isn't $\mathbb Z_9 \cong \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$ by this theorem?

Comment: How elements of order 9 does $\Bbb{Z}/9$ have?

Comment: That's given by Euler's $\varphi$ function. So it's 6.

Comment: So choose any one of those 6 elements in Z/9 and you'll see it generates the whole group. Does this work for Z/3 $\times$ Z/3?

Comment: @Pacman The Euler $\varphi$ function gives the order of the *multiplicative* group, not the additive group, which is what you're considering

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, one needs $\mathrm{gcd}(m,n) = 1$ for $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$.

Answer (score 11):

The theorem does indeed hold: $\Bbb Z_9$ is a "trivial" direct product; it's cyclic, and just itself! Or, you can think of it as $\Bbb Z_9 \times \{0\}$, the product of itself with the trivial group (which is also cyclic!).

Just because

> Every finite abelian group is the direct product of cyclic groups

that doesn't mean that every finite abelian group is the direct product *of cyclic groups of prime order*.

Comment: Hold on, but this says otherwise: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Finite_Abelian_Groups

Comment: It says internal direct product but isn't internal direct product isomorphic to external direct product?

Comment: @Pacman Prime *power* order. $9 = 3^2$ is a prime power, but not prime.

Comment: and because $\{0\}$ has order $p^0$, the result still holds?

Comment: Yep! $1$ is indeed a power of a prime, so the theorem still holds.

Answer (score 7):

More to the point: How many elements of order $9$ does $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_3$ have?

Comment: Is there a way to count without checking each element? Something like what Euler's $\varphi$ function does with $\mathbb Z_9$.

Comment: Can any element of $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_3$ have order greater than $3$?

Comment: The order of an element $(a,b) \in \mathbb Z_n \times \mathbb Z_m$ is lcm$(a,b)$?

Comment: No, thats not quite true. $|(a,b)|=[|a|,|b|]$, where $|x|$ is the order of $x$, and $[x,y]$ is lcm.

Comment: Mathematically, why can't any element of $\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$ have order greater than $3$?

Comment: Pick an actual element and look at successive powers.  It should become clear.

Comment: I see. If $(a,b) \in \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$, then $a \in \mathbb Z_3$ and $b \in \mathbb Z_3$, and neither can have order greater than $3$.

Comment: Yes, that's it. :)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers to this post have done a good job explaining this, but since you mentioned the Sylow theorems, you might want to look into at them to get the full picture here, particularly, the first, that reads:

> If $G$ is a $p$-group of order $\#G=mp^k$, then it has $p$-subgroups of order $p^i$ for every $p^i | p^k$

meaning that

> If $\# G$ is a multiple of $p^k$ then it has subgroups of orders equal to all possible powers of $p$ between $0$ and $k$ ($1, p, p^2, ... , p^{k-1}, p^k)$

So since $\# \mathbb Z_9=9=3^2$, a direct consequence of Sylow's 1st Theorem is that $\mathbb Z_3 \leq \mathbb Z_9$ (since we're talking about an abelian group, $\mathbb Z_3$ is a normal subgroup).

After that, the statement $\mathbb Z_9 \ncong \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$ becomes ovious if you take into consideration [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690951/direct-product-of-two-normal-subgroups) for avaluating direct products of subgroups.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see that $1$ is a generator of $\Bbb Z_9$

Now take any arbitary element of $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_3$, say (a,b).

Then the span of ($a$,$b$) = {($a$,$b$), ($2a$,$2b$), ($0$,$0$)}

Hence |span of ($a$,$b$)| <= $3$ < $9$ = |$\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_3$| i.e there is no single element generator of $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_3$. Thus, $\mathbb Z_9 \ncong \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$