# Finding a non-abelian group with $54$ elements non-isomorphic to $D_{27}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

My goal is to find a non-abelian group with $54$ elements non-isomorphic to $D_{27}$ and for that matter, I tried $\mathbb{Z_3} \times D_9$, now we have that $Z(\mathbb{Z_3} \times D_9) =\mathbb{Z_3} \times \{ id \}$ but $Z(D_{27})=\{id\}$. Is this a valid one?

Comment: Your question and the title don't match at all. But yes, $\mathbb{Z}_3\times D_9$ is a nonabelian group of order $54$ which is not dihedral.

Comment: If you meant $45$  as in the header question then [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108405/explicit-descriptions-of-groups-of-order-45).  But, really, it's not clear what you meant.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake

Comment: Yes, that is a valid example. There are others, also.

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: Just to know where you might end up: https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/NA.html